# In Keras, how to send each item in a batch through a model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a model that starts with a `Conv2D` layer and so it must take input of shape `(samples, rows, cols, channels)` (and the model must ultimately output a shape of `(1)`). However, for my purposes one full unit of input needs to be some (fixed) number of samples, so the overall input shape sent into this model when given a batch of input ends up being `(batch_size, samples, rows, cols, channels)` *(which is expected and correct, but...)*. How do I send each item in the batch through this model so that I end up with an output of shape `(batch_size, 1)`?

**What I have tried so far:**

I tried creating an inner model containing the `Conv2D` layer et al then wrapping the entire thing in a `TimeDistributed` wrapper, followed by a `Dense(units=1)` layer. This compiled, but resulted in an output shape of `(batch_size, samples, 1)`. I feel like I am missing something simple...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Why are you having this output?

I believe layers such as `Dense` and `Activation` used to accept only a 2-rank tensor of dimensions `(batch_size, features)` in earlier days. The following declaration would behave like your model, outputting predictions of shape `(batch_size, steps, 1)`:

```py
x = Input(shape=(299, 299, 3))
y = Conv2D(...)(x)
y = Conv2D(...)(y)
...
conv_model = Model(x, y)

x = Input(shape=(steps, 299, 299, 3))
y = TimeDistributed(conv_model)(x)
y = TimeDistributedDense(1)(y)  # or TimeDistributed(Dense(1))(y)

model = Model(x, y)
```

Whereas this would raise an error:

```py
x = Input(shape=(299, 299, 3))
y = Conv2D(...)(x)
y = Conv2D(...)(y)
...
conv_model = Model(x, y)

x = Input(shape=(steps, 299, 299, 3))
y = TimeDistributed(conv_model)(x)
y = Dense(1)(y)

model = Model(x, y)
```

But then some assumptions were taken so multiple existing layers (e.g. `BatchNormalization`, `Dropout`, `Activation`) could be applied in a larger context, such as RNNs' outputs.

Nowadays, `Dense` and `Activation` layers accept inputs of arbitrary rank and will, by default, operate in the last one (see the docs on [Dense](https://keras.io/layers/core/#dense)). Hence `TimeDistributed(Dense(1))` and `Dense(1)` are logically equivalent, but kept as valid choices for the users. You can read issue [#278](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/278) for more on this discussion.

### How to solve your problem?

#### Dealing with independent images

If the `samples` images in each input from your dataset don't hold any relationship other than the associated output (e.g. different captures of a same class).

I would start by keeping your conv model and combining the results with average pooling before applying the dense layer:

```py
x = Input(shape=(299, 299, 3))
y = Conv2D(...)(x)
y = Conv2D(...)(y)
...
y = Conv2D(kernels, ...)(y)
conv_model = Model(x, y)

x = Input(shape=(steps, 299, 299, 3))
y = TimeDistributed(conv_model)(x)
# K.get_variable_shape(y) == (?, samples, height/k, width/l, kernels)
y = GlobalAveragePooling3D()(y)
# K.get_variable_shape(y) == (?, kernels)
y = Dense(1)(y)
model = Model(inputs=x, outputs=y)
```

If you already have a `GlobalAveragePooling2D` layer in your `conv_model`, then a `GlobalAveraPooing1D` after the `TimeDistributed` wrapper will suffice.

#### Positionally related Images

If the `samples` images in an input of your dataset hold a positional relationship (e.g. they compose a 3D image with depth `samples`), then I would suggest you to try `conv 3D -> global pooling 3D -> dense`:

```py
x = Input(shape=(samples, height, width, channels))
y = Conv3D(...)(x)
y = Conv3D(...)(x)
...
y = Conv3D(kernels, ...)(x)
# K.get_variable_shape(y) == (?, samples/k, height/l, width/m, kernels)
y = GlobalAveragePooling3D()(y)
# K.get_variable_shape(y) == (?, kernels)
y = Dense(1)(y)  
# K.get_variable_shape(y) == (?, 1)
model = Model(inputs=x, outputs=y)
```

#### Temporally related Images

If the `samples` images in an input of your dataset hold a temporal relationship (e.g. sequential time increasing frames of a single capture), then I would go for a `TimeDistributed` conv model feeding a LSTM (and later for a `ConvLSTM2D`, as your answer suggests):

```py
x = Input(shape=(height, width, channels))
y = Conv2D(...)(x)
y = Conv2D(...)(x)
...
y = Conv2D(kernels, ...)(x)
y = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(y)
conv_model = Model(inputs=x, outputs=y)

x = Input(shape=(samples, height, width, channels)
y = TimeDistributed(conv_model)(x)
y = LSTM(..., return_sequences=True)(y)
y = LSTM(...)(y)
y = Dense(1)(y)

model = Model(inputs=x, outputs=y)
```

Let us know how you ended up implementing it :-)

Comment: In my case they were temporally related images (more specifically, framed spectrograms of continuous audio), so I ended up doing something like `ConvLSTM2D -> Conv2D -> GRU -> Dense`. Great answer!

Answer (score 1):

At the moment you are returning a 3D array.
Add a Flatten() layer to convert the array to 2D, and then add a Dense(1). This should output (batch_size, 1).

Comment: The input shape of `(None, samples, rows, cols, channels)` is correct for my purposes. I just need to know how to process it. I will edit the question to make this clearer

Comment: Could you elaborate I'm not sure I understand. You want the resultant array to be of shape (None,) correct?

Comment: `(None, 1)`. It's a classifier. But it needs to take as input x number of images, which together constitute a single input. That's why it is 5 dimensional instead of the usual 4 for conv nets

Comment: I think I understand what you mean I edited my answer

Comment: I could (Flatten), but the fact that I have a tensor of shape `(batch_size, samples, 1)` seems to indicate to me that the samples are not all getting processed by the conv net. Our conversation however has got me thinking and I think I have found the answer. I will write up an answer if it works. Thanks!

Comment: (I now see my thinking in the previous comment is incorrect. `Conv2D` outputs the same shape as its input, so the samples were in fact being processed.)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the answer was to use a [`ConvLSTM2D`](https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/#convlstm2d) layer as the first layer. This layer takes a 5-dimensional input shape and outputs a 4-dimensional output shape, which I can then feed into my `Conv2D` layer.